# Is this question valid for GD.SE?

Tags: support

First have a look at the question I want to ask:

> I have an image that I intend to show on [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prokeys/ekfnbpgmmeahnnlpjibofkobpdkifapn) publicly viewable page:
>   It has the logos of:
>
> 1. GMail
> 2. Twitter
> 3. Facebook
> 4. Google+
> 5. The Verge
> 6. Forbes
> 7. Mashable
> 8. TheNextWeb
> 9. Reddit
> 10. Outlook
>
> It has just the logos, and is intended to tell users that my app works on these websites. My app is free and doesn't cost users anything.
>   Is it safe to show this image considering that it has too many logos in it? I don't want to arise any problems regarding copyright or trademark.

Is this question valid on this site. If not, please tell me where I should post it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general disclaimer: We are not lawyers. Since your asking about legal matters you should be asking **Your** lawyer. (that is the forum)

Design wise its probably ok tough. So if you were intending to ask about the design i would say its fine. But then you need to clearly state so.

If your asking about the legal then you need to look up each of those individual companies logo use policy. In this case i would say the question is probably askable. However, your unlikely to get a satisfactory answer. Because:

a) Its research intensive, and you have shown no willingness to do the research.
b) Our opinion researched or not bears little value in court.

So I would say Maybe.

PS the answer to your question is NO

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had however, researched, and found logo use policies for only Twitter, Fb, G+, Gmail, and Reddit - and none other. I just wanted to be more careful.